# Ngif else with css [Angular]

Tags: angular

is there a way to define that when my condition is not true, my component gets other attribute styles in Angular? i want to define my main css file.

i want something like this:

`example (s-help.component.html):` (not correct)

```
<div *ngIf="visible; else class="test" " >
   <div class="s-help-content "><span [translate]="text"></span></div>
</div>
```

`css`

```
.s-help{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center left calc(0.37em + 0.37rem);
    background-size: calc(1em + 1rem) calc(1em + 1rem);
    border: 2px solid $warning !important;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block !important;   
    color: $gray-700;
    min-width: 220px;
    white-space: normal !important;
    padding-left: 5px !important;
    padding-right: 5px !important;

}
.s-help-content {
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 6px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-right: 6px;
}

.test {
    display: none;
}
```

`component used in code`

```
<s-help [visible]="true" [ngClass]="'s-help'" [text]="'INFOTEXT.101' | translate"></s-help>
```

my issue is that the border of the component is visible all time, even if the condition is false

to make it more clear: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-etrn9z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomp%2Fcomp.component.html **i dont want the border under the first info text**

Comment: Take a look at [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) and [NgStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need? `ngClass` will take a javascript expression as an input, here you can conditionally add the class or remove if needed!

```
<div *ngIf="visible" [ngClass]="!visible ? 'test' : ''" >
   <div class="s-help-content "><span [translate]="text"></span></div>
</div>
```

[updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qyfynn)

Comment: this was a good intention, but i dont know whats the problem, there is still the border! in my code i add the component, i edited my example.

Comment: @du7ri please share a stackblitz! this question is being asked a lot of times, if provided maybe ur problem will be resolved!\

Comment: @du7ri in your question, you still don't have a condition applied with ngClass. Can you update your answer with the ngClass that has a conditional applied?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-etrn9z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomp%2Fcomp.component.html

Comment: when the visible condition is false, i dont want to see the border, i hope now its clear, i dont know it the ngif else is the best way to do it, but im a beginner in angular

Comment: @du7ri Thank you so much, is this the expected output [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qyfynn)

Comment: yes, i want that if the visible condition is false, the div isnt visible anymore, i dont want to see the blue div border, under my info div, i need to tell when the condition is false, that the display is none

Comment: no :( i dont want to see the blue div, when the "hi" text is not displayed

Comment: @du7ri That is what my stackblitz is doing check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qyfynn)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247454/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-du7ri).